# Files in git showing as not staged after previously staging and committing files

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I have just staged and committed a handful of files locally to my Git repo. I was in line with the remote repo, so after I performed the `git commit` I done a `git status` and was expecting to see that I was one commit ahead of the repo.

However, what I found was that all of the files that were changed have found themselves still marked as modified and are once again outside of the staging area.

I committed some new previously untracked files in this commit. Those files are *not* listed as changed, so they must have been committed successfully.

What I don't understand is why are these other files showing as changed/unstaged again?

I am using Git 1.8.2.1.

What I find confusing is when I do a `git add -A` and add all the files again and then commit it *does* recognise them. Why does it sometimes take two commits to get the desired result?

This is the output from the terminal when I firstly do a `git status`, the `git commit` and finally another `git status` to see where I am:

```
# On branch CRMPICCO-1872
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/CRMPICCO-1872' by 3 commits.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   sass/iphone/page/sun.scss
#       modified:   web/load/sun.inc.php
#       modified:   web/content/iphone/sun.inc.php
#       modified:   web/css/compressed/iphone/checkout.css
#       modified:   web/css/compressed/iphone/style.css
#       modified:   web/scripts/iphone/js/iphone.js
#       modified:   web/scripts/jquery_mobile/swipe/swipe.jquery.js

git commit -m 'My Commit Message In Here'

[CRMPICCO-1872 5f248ca] My Commit Message In Here  4 files changed, 45 insertions(+), 54 deletions(-)

git status

# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/CRMPICCO-1872' by 4 commits.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   web/content/iphone/sun.inc.php
#       modified:   web/css/compressed/iphone/checkout.css
#       modified:   web/css/compressed/iphone/style.css
```

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of it just happening right now (again).

[image]

Comment: It would help to show an example of the commands you execute to recreate the problem.

Comment: @Gauthier Yes, I have just updated my question as it has happened again.

Comment: My first guess would be line ending confusion...

Comment: Great. A commit was created (branch ahead by 4 commits instead of 3). Check your history in gitk and verify that this new commit introduced the changes you expected. Then check the unstaged changes (I mean the red dot in gitk) and see how they differ from the new commit. What changed with the new commit, what changed after?

Comment: @twalberg You might be on to something there as I did hit enter to go down a line with my commit message. Have you experienced this before?

Comment: are you using linux and do you work on a local drive with a linux-y filesystem (such as e.g. ext3/4) that can store permissions alright and did you leave the settings concerning autoclrf, gitattributes/filters, hooks ... alone? if your enviornment is different from that default case described before, please mention it.

Comment: @mnagel I am working on a Win7 machine with a CentOS 5.6 VM running, this is my development environment. My current Git config is set as `core.autocrlf=input`. I have not configured any filters or hooks, you will see `#commit` in my commit message in the screenshot, but this is a built-in hook with my VCS host and nothing I have configured. Is my SS clear enough that you can see the problem?

Comment: Could this be something to do with the version of Git I am using? Is it worth upgrading?